# Can a Android set top boxes run PC games?

Tags: linux, android

I was searching for set top boxes, I have seen some with really high performance, and I was wondering their boundaries.

The best ones I have seen so far were:

ODROID-X2

GK802

MK809 II

Minix NEO X5

And well, I have seen that all of those have Android 4.1 or newer as they default O.S, but I have also seen all of those run Ubuntu, in video reviews and text ones.

I have also seen that this specific GPU which is used in Allwinner A31 (which is actually a tablet) can run Windows 8.

Since those 4 mentioned Mini-PCS can run Ubuntu, I was wondering if they would be able to run games such as new Steam Linux games, World of Warcraft, multiplayer 3D games?

Because all of those have: Vivante GC2000 or ARM Mali-400 of GPU, which can easily run OpenGL, and GC2000 OpenGL 2.0, which goes up to 24 GFLOPS which is unbelievable for such small device.

Would I be able to run WoW or Steam games on those? (since wow runs on Linux by using Wine, and steam games have native Linux OpenGL)

Comment: 24 GFLOPS isn't that much. A GTX 670, one of the most popular GPUs, can run about 2459.5 GFLOPS.

Comment: GTX 670 goes up to 2460 GFLOPS on a desktop, has a considerable power consumption (but is actually low comparing to other high end gpus), and has a big size, I was meaning 24GFLOPS for a small device that is only twice a common flash drive.

Comment: @GuilhermeGarcia: You could try to run a game on one of those computers. I doubt it'll run well (or at all), but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @therefromhere please don't encourage users to re-ask their questions on other sites. Comments like that lead to duplication when a question gets migrated. In the future please just vote/flag to close/migrate - the commend isn't necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quite simply no. Every single 'mini pc' you've mentioned runs the arm architecture. All these games run on the x86/x86_64 architecture. Until these games have an arm port, its impossible.

These PCs run a port (a recompiled/tweaked varient) of Ubuntu for that specific Arm varient, made possible by Ubuntu being FOSS. Open source software can be ported, but very few commercial PC games are ported to Arm. Steam is X86 only as well (though for some reason they sort of assume you know that). It isn't just an OS issue - these systems are fundamentally *unlike* a standard x86 PC despite being called 'mini pcs'